# CSS grid of squares laid out in columns not rows

Tags: javascript, html, css

I currently have a grid made out of square DIVs (200px x 200px each).

I have started in the top left hand corner and floated each one left so that the 2nd one is to the right of the first and the the third to the right of that and so on. When it runs out of horizontal space in it's container the next square automatically starts a new row, obviously.

This is great if you want the grid to keep getting longer vertically each time a row fills up, but I want mine to be three squares high and grow to the right hand side, so the first square goes in the top left, the 2nd underneath it, the third underneath that, then (because the container is 600px high) the 4th square should start a new column and go to the right of the first.

Is it possible to achieve this for an unspecified number of squares so it just keeps growing into new columns without resorting to javascript?

IE6 support is not necessary.

Any help would really be appreciated.

Comment: What about placing the divs inside a div container (200px x 600px) and then floating that left?

Comment: i can forsee many issues in doing this without some type of wrappers. you may be better off making div wrappers the height of 3 of the divs.  dont float the inner div, only the wrapper. for every 3rd div, just close and open a new div. are you building the divs from an array or some type of loop?

Comment: How about Masonry? http://masonry.desandro.com/index.html

Comment: wrapping the divs is one option, but as I've commented on one of the other answers the squares are output dynamically so I'd have to create the wrapper on each group of 3 squares using jquery once the grid has loaded. It is an option though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try CSS 3's multi columns http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/ , http://www.css3.info/preview/multi-column-layout/

Using properties like

```
-moz-column-width: 5em;
-webkit-column-width: 5em;
-moz-column-gap: 1em;
-webkit-column-gap: 1em;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Txgnk/1/

Looks like IE 10 is the first IE to support it http://caniuse.com/multicolumn

Comment: I'd love to use this but as usual IE gets in the way :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<style>
.parent {
  height:600px;
  white-space: nowrap;       
}

.child {
  width: 200px;
  height: 600px;
  display:inline-block;       
}

.grand-child {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
</style>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <div class="grand-child"></div>
    <div class="grand-child"></div>
    <div class="grand-child"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <div class="grand-child"></div>
    <div class="grand-child"></div>
    <div class="grand-child"></div>
  </div>
  ...
  ...
</div>
```

Comment: The squares will be output to the page dynamically one at a time, so the only way I can think to wrap each group of three squares in a <div class="child"> is by using javascript once they're on the page?

Comment: @jonhobbs: How can they be output one at a time if not with JS? If so, why the requirement for no JS?

Comment: If you are using javascript, you could dynamically create "child" div and append "grand-child" div as they are created. Create a new "child" div after every three "grand-child" divs. This could be easily done if you use any javascript library like, jquery.